# Making sidebar menu wider results in problems when toggling the menu because width stays fixed (Keenthemes Metronic)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, metronic

Im working on an angular web app. A Keenthemes Metronic sidebar has been added. Some of the menu texts are too long and they overlap other elements. I know that I can fix this by doing:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

But I want to show the menu titles fully. So I want to expand the menu so that the text fits. I tried out various kind of width content styling but it doesn't work. I also tried to set a fixed width on the sidebar and the heading part (collapse button) and this worked. But this introduces a new problem. When the collapse button is clicked, the width stays fixed and hinders the sidebar to collapse.

I have unsuccessfully tried to find Keenthemes Metronic docs. Do anyone know how I can tackle this problem?

---

The sidebar can be seen here: https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic-v4/theme/admin_1/layout_sidebar_menu_light.html

I can make the sidebar wider by setting the width to e.g.:

```
width: 280px;
```

And this gives enough space for all menu titles, which is exactly what I want.

But when I click on the mini menu toggler button it fails to toggle the menu because the width of the menu stays fixed at 280px.

Comment: Try `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @Dominik That doesn't work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has confirmed that the issue was due to targeting the wrong class, and thus outside the scope of the question as posted. (See the author's notes in the comments to proposed answers.)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, you need to inline (with white-space: nowrap) and hide the last characters (with overflow: hidden) :

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: As stated in my question, I want to show the titles fully and therefore I want to make the sidebar wider. I'm aware of the ellipsis text overflow, but I don't want to hide the last characters...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have posted my css code - my bad. I found out that I was targeting the wrong class.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the sidebar via the toggler button, it adds the class `page-sidebar-menu-closed` to the `ul`. Unfortunately, this is too low in the DOM for us to handle the CSS easily.

BUT, it also changes the class of the `body`:

Open:

```
<body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-content-white" ...
```

Closed:

```
<body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-content-white page-sidebar-closed" ...
```

So, on your width, you just want to specify that it doesn't applies to the "closed" version of the sidebar:

```css
body:not(.page-sidebar-closed) div.page-sidebar {
  width: 180px;
}
```

Or, you could go the other way and set the width back when the sidebar is closed:

```css
div.page-sidebar {
  width: 180px;
}

body.page-sidebar-closed div.page-sidebar {
  width: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have posted my css code - my bad. I found out that I was targeting the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution ! Unfortunately i had to globally replace "width:235px" to my desired width (270px) in file "theme\assets\layouts\layout\css\layout.min.css"